# How to customize buttonbar in android?

Tags: android, button, buttonbar

I made a **button bar** that contains some buttons in it, I faced two problems:

The first one is that when the buttons fill the width of the screen the new ones begin to behave wrongly: [see from here](https://imageshack.com/i/0dxpczp)

I had try setting width to `wrap_content` and *some fixed values* but both didn't work.

The second one is that I want the buttons to appear like if they are merged in the **buttonbar** and only separated by simple lines, [Like That](https://imageshack.com/i/ns8xm4p).

**here's my xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Home" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid1"
        android:layout_width="875dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        style="@android:style/ButtonBar" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/main"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/HomeView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Main"
            android:text="@string/homeview" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Lighting"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/HomeView"
            android:text="@string/lighting" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/A.C."
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Lighting"
            android:text="@string/ac" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Profiles"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/A.C."
            android:text="@string/profiles" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Movies"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Profiles"
            android:text="@string/movies" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Music"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Movies"
            android:text="@string/music" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/TVShows"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Music"
            android:text="@string/tvshows" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Remote"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TVShows"
            android:text="@string/remote" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: "the new ones begin to behave wrongly" is dependent on what your desired behavior is. What do you want to happen?

Comment: just be regular buttons, see the image link i included to see what i mean by behave wrongly

Answer (score 0):

1) What Layout do you use?

Try to use `LinearLayout` and set each item `layout_weihgt = 1` in XML.
Also item's width must be `match_parent`.

2) You must create custom layout for buttons.

Comment: i made that but it gives me the same result, i attached my code just take a look at it